# handling multiple arguments in bash script

Tags: bash, while-loop, arguments

I have a script that needs multiple input arguments.
I'm trying to use the same method from another script which has only one argument and works fine, but adding arguments is not working.

The base code I'm trying to use is:

```
while test "${#}" -gt 0; do
  case "${1}" in
    --password=*) PASSWORD="${1#*=}"; shift 1;; # string
    *) usage "Unknown option: ${1}";;
 esac
done
```

How can I add more arguments to this block?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add more cases to the `case` statement for other arguments.

Comment: E.g. `--user=*) user="${1#*=}"; shift 1;;`

Comment: See [BashFAQ #35: "How can I handle command-line options and arguments in my script easily?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035)

Comment: Or edit question to show exact use case of *"needs multiple input arguments"* AND show evidence of *"but adding arguments is not working"*. Good luck.

Comment: @barmar thank you for your quick response. I tested that before, but I notice a mistake thanks to your example. It´s working now.

Comment: Side note: The loop is awkward and using `shift` to discard arguments can be confusing. Better approaches: (a) Just iterate over arguments, don’t `shift` them: `for arg in "$@"; do case "$arg" in ...` (b) Or if you insist on using some indices: `for ((i = 1; i <= $#; ++i)); do case "${!i}" in ...`

Comment: Use $2 $3 etc in your script for next set of arguments.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek The "use $1 + shift" idiom is well established, predating new features like indirect variable references.

Comment: @Barmar Not all traditions are good traditions. The problem with `shift` is that it discards arguments in an awkward way (keeping `$0` and shifting everything else) and (more importantly) that it discards any arguments at all, making it impossible to (re)inspect the command line elsewhere in the script.